# Scala curly braces verbosity?

Tags: scala, curly-braces

I realize that more often than not Scala allows you to write something in many different ways. I came across the below code snippets.

```
case class A() extends C {}
```

and

```
case class B() extends C
```

where C is some class

I would like to know if there is any fundamental difference in its performance/functionality.

If not, why would someone prefer the snippet with curly braces over the one without them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference between the two. From the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (Chapter 5.3):

> The class body
>   {stats} may also be omitted, in which case the empty body {} is assumed

*Why would someone prefer the snippet with curly braces*? I don't know if anyone would, but I can assume this syntax is valid for clarity and completeness of the syntax: usually when Scala provides a shorthand for something ("syntactic sugar"), the full syntax ("de-sugared") is also valid.